# How to Query between a date range in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

[image: DEMO Table structure is here]

I'm querying

```
SELECT * FROM tempLog WHERE date BETWEEN '23-03-2017' AND '02-04-2017'
```

and the result is null. How to fix this. But

```
SELECT * FROM tempLog WHERE date BETWEEN '23-03-2017' AND '30-03-2017'
```

giving me the correct result.
Note:- tempLog is the table name.

Comment: What is the datatype of the date column?

Comment: Your first stop, in situations like this, is always [**the documentation**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

Comment: @GurV varchar   is the datatype

Answer (score 3):

You should store dates in `date` format or atleast correctly formatted string (YYYY-MM-DD).

For now you can use [**`str_to_date`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert the string to date and compare:

```
select *
from tempLog
where str_to_date(date, '%d-%m-%Y') between '2017-03-23' and '2017-04-02';
```

However note that this will hinder the optimizer from using index on the column if any.

The correct remedy of the situation is fixing the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html), you're supposed to use this format when writing a date: `'YYYY-MM-DD'` (although it says it may accept `'YYYYMMDD'` or even `YYYYMMDD` in some contexts).

Comment: Is that compulsory?

Comment: @SubratKumar - Yes, but it won't work if your column is of varchar type and format is exactly how it looks in the screenshot.

Comment: You can use DATE_FORMAT for other format, and your installation may use a different date format, but @pjehan is right for most setups